# Accessing UINavigationController from other file

Tags: objective-c, class, uinavigationcontroller

!!!Yes, it's a noob question, but yeah.

So I created a navigation controller in file1, which contains a table view. The cells in that table view are custom cells, having a different class and xib (file2). On the file2 xib, I have a button, which when clicked, should push a view into the navigation controller.

Now I don't know how to refer, from file2, to the navigation controller created in file1.

Edit: Fixed this by setting up the navigation controller in AppDelegate and creating a shared delegate, but what if I were to set up the navigation controller in file1?

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would prefer having a `delegate` in **file2**.

The .h file could look be something like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)buttonClicked;
@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;

- (void)getImageWithCompletionHandler:(handler)completionBlock;

@end
```

and then when creating the `CustomCell`object in the **file1** u need to set the `delegate` as `self`.

```
CustomCell *customCell = …
….
customCell.delegate = self;
```

Implement the `CustomCellDelegate` in **file1**

```
- (void)buttonClicked
{ 
  // TODO: push using navigation controller code.
}
```

The above is the **delegation pattern**. For more about `delegates` check out the tutorial [here](http://www.hardcodedstudios.com/home/ryan-newsome/simpledelegatetutorialforiosdevelopment)

According to **MVC (Model view controller) pattern** view's job is to just display the data and its the controller job to push or present the other controller.

**Hope this helps!**